# CSS Background for a div will only display color, not the image

Tags: css, html, background-image, background-color

When I apply a CSS `background` to my `div` tag, the color will work but the `background-image` will not display.

I want the `background-image` to be repeated across the bottom of my divs, but even if I only apply `background-image: url('assets/shadow.png');` without `position`, `repeat`, or `background-color`, it will still not show up. Only white is displayed.

But if I apply `background-color: #ECECFB;` the `background-color` WILL show up correctly in the background.

Why doesn't `background-image` work?

**CSS**

```
#slider-container,#footer-container,#main aside {
    background-color: #ECECFB;
    background-image: url('assets/shadow.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: bottom;
}
```

The image is linked correctly. Image is 15px by 12px.

I tried shorthand CSS background and only color was displayed.

Comment: first question. is the url to the image correct? then have you tried using firebug or chrome equivalent to see what's rendered on the page. this can help identify problems.

Comment: try creating a http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Nevermind, i was stupid and actually linked the image wrong. I needed to add a ../ in the url.

Comment: You need two values for background position.

Comment: I need two values for background position even when I use repeat-x? Don't I only need the vertical positioning?

Comment: It still sounds like the most likely culprit is that the image is not in fact being loaded. Check the network tab in Chrome dev tools.

Comment: I solved the problem, I needed to add ../ to go up a directory.
Thanks everyone :]

Comment: so... my answer was correct? Sweet!

Comment: OP, your question is erroneous.  You state that the _"image is linked correctly"_, yet later in comments you state that this was your whole problem.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 2):

Look at my fiddle below, notice it works fine. If the image does not download (i.e. bad url) then the background colour will only appear. Check the location or the network tab on chrome dev tools to see if the background image is not being loaded (404).

```
<div class="foo"></div>
.foo {
 background-color: red;
 background-image: url(http://subtlepatterns.subtlepatterns.netdna-cdn.com/patterns/blackorchid.png);
 background-repeat: repeat-x;
 background-position: bottom;
 height: 500px;
 width: 500px;   
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/XCbK4/

Answer (score 0):

The `background` property also can be used to display images.

#### Syntax

```
background: color position size repeat origin clip attachment image;
```

When using `background` and `background-image` at the same time you may have a conflict. I assume using `background-color` is behaving different for some reason or it may be significant in which order you use them.

This will of course give you the color instead of the image, too:

```
#slider-container,#footer-container,#main aside {
    background-image: url('assets/shadow.png');
    background: #ECECFB;  // overwriting the image
}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. I hope it will help:

```
#slider-container,#footer-container,#main aside {
background: #ECECFB url('assets/shadow.png') repeat-x bottom
}
```